# Im trying to dynamically change the url of an iframe but Im getting an Error: Unsafe value used in resource URL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe

Im trying to dynamically change the src of an iframe using angular 2 Ive tried

HTML

```
<iframe class="controls" width="580" height="780" src="{{controllerSrc}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

COMPONENT.TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery: any;
const $ = jQuery;

export class VideoplayerComponent implements OnInit {
    controllerSrc: string;


ngOnit(){

    $('.button1').click(function(){
        this.controllerSrc = 'https://www.videoindexer.ai/embed/insights/0c7357bd5c/?widgets=people';
});
}

}
```

but Im getting an error that says

`ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)`

not sure how else I can do this, any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First of all remove jQuery from your mind,while you are learning
>   Angular2 or +,
>
> Otherwise, you will never know how to do it in Angular way.

---

Here how you can achieve same thing without jQuery

> Component side :

```
// to remove error : Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class VideoplayerComponent implements OnInit {
    controllerSrc: string;
    constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

    ngOnit(){
        this.controllerSrc = this.getSafeUrl('https://www.videoindexer.ai/embed/insights/0c7357bd5c/?widgets=people');
    }

    // to remove error : Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context
    getSafeUrl(url) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)
    }

    changeIframe() {
        this.controllerSrc = this.getSafeUrl('your-new-url');
    }

}
```

> Template side :

```
<button (click)='changeIframe()'></button>

<iframe class="controls" width="580" height="780" [src]="controllerSrc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: still getting the same error as I was getting before `ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)`

Comment: now it wont compile and Im getting the error `Type 'SafeUrl' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: @A61NN5, try now chnage the `getSafeUrl` and `src` from iframe

Comment: @A61NN5, May I know reason why dont you accept my answer? , as its mor explaintory and given same solution ?

Comment: @A61NN5, and where did he explained how to change the url dynamically , that was your original question , right?

Comment: Both times I tried using the code you gave me I got the unsafe url error then whilst awaiting your reply Abinesh posted and I tried doing it his way and It worked first go, from there I can change the url variable. Im going to rephrase the question as `getting unsafe value in a resource context` sorry for misunderstanding I cant mark you both right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158568/discussion-between-a61nn5-and-vivek-doshi).

Answer (score 5):

No need of Jquery. Use Angular DomSanitizer

```
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
    export class VideoplayerComponent implements OnInit {
        controllerSrc: any;
         constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

        ngOnit(){
           const url='https://www.videoindexer.ai/embed/insights/0c7357bd5c/?widgets=people';
           this.controllerSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);

        }
}


<iframe class="controls" width="580" height="780" [src]="controllerSrc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Please refer to the docs [Angular DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Comment: This way we cannot append JWT token.